# Why is this Python implementation of trigonometric interpolation not working properly?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, python, interpolation

Consider a signal $u_j, j = 0, 1, \dots, N-1,$ sampled on an evenly-spaced grid of points, $x_j$. Define the discrete Fourier transform of $u_j$ by

$$U_k := \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1}u_je^{-(2\pi i k) j/ N},$$

and set $U_k := a_k + ib_k$ to explicitly denote the real and imaginary parts of $U_k$.

This [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHixjWHr-18) shows by Fourier analysis that the function

$$Q(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_{k}\cos\left(2\pi k \frac{x - x_0}{x_{N-1} - x_0}\right) - b_{k}\sin\left(2\pi k \frac{x - x_0}{x_{N-1} - x_0}\right)$$

is an interpolation of the signal $u_j$ in the sense that $Q(x_j) = u_j$ for all $j$. My attempt to code this interpolation is

```
  1 import torch 
  2 import numpy as np
  3 from scipy.fftpack import fft
  4
  5
  6
  7 def _get_inter_coeffs(x: torch.Tensor) -> np.array:
  8     y = fft(x.cpu().numpy())
  9     a, b = y.real, y.imag
 10     return a, b
 11 
 12 def trig_interpolate(xn: torch.Tensor, x: torch.Tensor, u:torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
 13     x0 = x[0].item()
 14     L = (x[-1] - x0).item()
 15     a, b = _get_inter_coeffs(u)
 16     N = len(a)
 17 
 18     xn = xn.cpu().numpy()
 19     d = xn - x0
 20     un = np.zeros_like(xn)
 21     for k, (ak, bk) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
 22         un += ak*np.cos(2*np.pi*k*(d /L))-bk*np.sin(2*np.pi*k*(d /L))
 23     return (1/N)*torch.Tensor(un)
 24 
 25 if __name__ == '__main__':
 26     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 27     x = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 256)[:-1]
 28     u = torch.cos(np.pi*x)
 29     xn = torch.Tensor([-0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
 30     un = trig_interpolate(xn, x, u)
 31 
 32     plt.plot(x, u, c = 'blue')
 33     plt.scatter(xn, un, c = 'red')
 34     plt.show()
 35     plt.close()
 36 
 37     u = torch.randn_like(x)
 38     un = trig_interpolate(xn, x, u)
 39 
 40     plt.plot(x, u, c = 'blue')
 41     plt.scatter(xn, un, c = 'red')
 42     plt.show()
 43     plt.close()
 44 
 45     x = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 16)[:-1]
 46     xhres = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 256)
 47     u = torch.cos(np.pi*x)
 48     uhres = torch.cos(np.pi*xhres)
 49     un = trig_interpolate(x, x, u)
 50 
 51     plt.plot(xhres, uhres, c = 'blue')
 52     plt.scatter(x, un, c = 'red')
 53     plt.scatter(x, u, c = 'green')
 54     plt.show()
 55     plt.close()
```

Note in line 23 that I use the normalization $1/N$ because `scipy.fftpack.fft` does not use the normalization $1/\sqrt{N}$. The first two tests work fine:
[image: Output of first test]
[image: Output of second test.]

However, the third test is way off. For clarity, the third test is in lines 45-55. At this point, I'm just trying to compute the interpolation at the sampled points $x_j$ (line 49). From theory, these values should be exactly the same as $u_j$. But this is what I obtain:

[image: Output of third test.].

Can anyone help me to figure out what's going on?

Comment: it is quite hard to follow u. Would u try reducing your question to a minimal one? also, did you look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel ? It might solve all of your problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest using the Dirichlet interpolation. The basic idea is the interpolation via the Fourier transform:

$$f(x)=\sum_k \hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}$$

Here is an implementation for arbitrary chosen samples (they do not have to be equally spaced):

```
fs = 8
x = np.arange(fs * 2) / fs
y = np.sin(np.pi * x) + np.cos(np.pi * x * 2) + np.cos(np.pi * x * 3)
Y = np.fft.fft(y)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1], 1 / fs)

upSampRatio = 5

fsNew = fs * upSampRatio
xInterps = np.arange(2 * fsNew) / fsNew

Y = np.concatenate([Y, [np.conjugate(Y[fs])]])
freq = np.concatenate([freq, [-freq[fs]]])

yInterp = np.array([
    np.dot(Y, np.exp(freq * 2j * np.pi * xInterp) / x.shape[-1]) 
    for xInterp in xInterps
])

plt.figure(figsize=[15, 5])
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(xInterps, yInterp.real)
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.legend(['Original', 'Resampled'])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Attached the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel).